# How to update all the column values with empty strings to null in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update all the empty strings in my whole database with null? I have used select into #temptable in stored procedure to extract values from source to target. But there are many empty strings in the database. Now i need to update those empty strings with Null. Is there any option to update all the columns at once in stored procedure. Please help me

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Get all columns of a character type from the dictionary, build dynamic queries on the basis of that and execute them.

Comment: Its SQL server. sorry  I have edited

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this result. It will give you the list of only nullable strings columns with update statement :

```
SELECT
    'UPDATE ' +QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+ QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + ' SET ' +  QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + '=NULL WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + '='''';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND C.DATA_TYPE LIKE '%CHAR'
AND C.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
```

Comment: I'd advice to 1) include the schema name before the table name, 2) use `QUOTENAME` for table, schema and column names and 3) make sure that `C.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'` because you are about to set all the values as `NULL`

Comment: @EzLo Thanks for double checking. When I start to create the script in my mind I used nullables only. But when I start to write it somehow I put is_nullable='NO'. Also same thing for table_schema. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is something like this....very consuming but might help:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = ''



    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                    AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END   
    END

    SELECT distinct ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```

This will show you where (tables and columns) you have empty string values (remember that there is different kinds of...empty string)

then just go through each table and run this

```
Update myTable set MyColumn = NULL where Field = ''
```

you can reuse it by not dropping the #results table and adding a row_number to it and then create a looped sequence to get things updated in sequence as well. Hope this somehow helps, but that's probably what I would do.